# how to solve 2x=4 in $Z_{12}$

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

How do I solve 2x=4 in $Z_{12}$

I know the $gcd(2,12) = 2$ and $2|4$ therefore there are 2 solutions, but I'm not sure how to solve this. I tried using the euclidean algorithm but it doesn't seem to work with numbers this small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align}{\bf Hint}\qquad\ \ \   2x&\equiv 2a\!\pmod{\!2n}\\[.2em]
\iff  \color{#c00}2x &= \color{#c00}2a + \color{#c00}2nk \ \ \ {\rm for\ some}\ \ k\in\Bbb Z\\[.2em]
\iff\ \   x &= \ \ a +\ \  nk \ \ \ {\rm for\ some}\ \ k\in\Bbb Z\\[.2em]
\iff\  \ x&\equiv\ \ a\!\pmod{\!n}
\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

That's very simple: since $d$ divides all coefficients and the modulus, you can simplify, since $\mathbf Z$ is an integral domain:
$$2x\equiv 4\mod 12\iff x\equiv 2\mod 6$$

Comment: At this level you should explain why that is true (if the OP knew  they probably wouldn't ask the question)

Comment: I've added a hint (integral domain). I think the O.P. think from this hint, and ask for more if he/she does see why.

Comment: Ok thank you, so just to be clear, you can only simplify like this when $Z_m$ is an integral domain? also why is Z an integral domain in this case as 12 is not prime??

Comment: @user520403 I elaborated in my answer. As you can see, it amounts to cancelling $2$ in $\,\Bbb Z,\,$ which is possible since $2$ is a nonzero element of a domain, so not a zero-divisor.

Comment: No. What I meant is that, as $\mathbf Z$ is an integral domain, when you interpret the congruence in terms of integers, you can simplify and interpret the relation you obtain as another congruence. Is tat clear?